# Over an algebraically closed field, is it possible to factor a symmetric invertible matrix $A$ as $X^T X$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that this result is true when the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$. (Though I don't remember why.) Does it also hold for algebraically closed fields? Can someone give me a hint as to why this is true?

Comment: The reuse of $T$ is confusing. Do you mean to say that an arbitrary matrix $A$ can be written as $A = B^TB$?

Comment: Also, do you specifically mean the transpose as opposed to the conjugate transpose (AKA adjoint)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm pretty sure that it's just the transpose, since one only specifies that the original matrix $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This is used in the complex case on page 58 of Miranda's Riemann Surfaces and Algebraic Curves in order to prove that the smooth conics in $P^2$ are isomorphic to $P^1$. I want to prove this for conics in $P^2$ for some arbitrary (algebraically closed) field, so it was natural to ask about this extension. So for my purposes it would really need to be the transpose.

Comment: This is apparently a consequence of [Takagi's factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Takagi.27s_factorization), and this is the first I'm hearing of it.  Neat stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factorization is an immediate consequence of [Takagi's factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Takagi.27s_factorization), which itself is a corollary of the following theorem:

**From Horn and Johnson:** (p. 203, first edition)

> Let $A \in M_n$ be given.  There exists a unitary $U \in M_n$ and an upper triangular $\Delta$ such that $A = U\Delta U^T$ if and only if all the eigenvalues of $A \overline A$ are real and non-negative.  Under this condition, the main diagonal entries of $\Delta$ may be chosen to be non-negative.

It seems that the answer lies behind this theorem. The question is fundamentally whether it can be extended to handle $A \in M_n(\Bbb F)$ for arbitrary (algebraically closed fields) $\Bbb F$.

Comment: It looks like this might work; [Schur decomposition](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/245669/81360) does seem to extend nicely, along with the notion of an [inner product](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185403/do-there-exist-vector-spaces-over-a-finite-field-that-have-a-dot-product).