# Is it possible to define an inner product on a vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $p$ (obviously) prime. Is it possible to define an inner product and/or norm over $V$?

I am curious if this is possible. I am getting a bit confused about the positive-definiteness axioms of inner products. Every member of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is greater than or equal to $0$, but does this cause trouble? If this is not possible, why?

Comment: The field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (it is standard to put the $p$ before the second occurrence of $\mathbb{Z}$, not after) is not an ordered field.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang could you explain why a field that is not ordered cannot have an inner product?

Comment: Because the definition of "inner product" requires there to be a notion of "nonnegativity" in the base field.

Comment: Sometimes "inner product" is used to mean just a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form, and you can study these over finite fields. See other posts like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262315/questions-about-a-vector-space-over-a-finite-field-with-a-bilinear-symmetric-for).