# Examples of Clifford algebras over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, inner-products, clifford-algebras

Yesterday I was in a discussion about solving an applied problem using clifford algebras over a finite field.  While this is not (seemingly) disallowed by the definition of a clifford algebra (which seems to either say it can be over a field or over a ring depending on who you consult), there is some ambiguity about how much sense an [inner product makes on a finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49348/inner-product-spaces-over-finite-fields) depending on the chosen finite field since it must induce a vector space.

This led to some ineffective googling where I tried to find examples of clifford algebras over finite fields:  I could not!

So: Are there (applied?) examples of Clifford algebras over finite fields that are studied or are these generally uninteresting?

Comment: Clifford algebras are defined with quadratic forms, not inner products. In characteristic not 2, quadratic forms are equivalent to symmetric bilinear forms, of which an "inner product" is usually a particular type. There is no ambiguity here. I do not have any "natural" examples of such Clifford algebras, but constructing examples is easy. Probably you would want to look towards number theory.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff thanks for the clarification, the relation between inner product and symmetric bilinear form dispelled my sense of ambiguity.

Comment: If you scrutinize the definition of a [quaternion algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra) you'll see that they are 2D Clifford algebras, and I seem to be getting a lot of hits searching for quaternion algebras over finite fields.